# C# Exception while executing sqlCE query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

When I am running this script manual it is working but when I am running it in c# with Entity Framework I am getting an exception

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(script); //Exception
```

Sql script:

```
CREATE TABLE [Customers]
(
   [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
   [Name] NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
   [Email] NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
   [Phone] NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
   [Address] NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
   [Suburb] NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
   [Postcode] NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
   [Number] INT NOT NULL
);
GO
ALTER TABLE [Customers] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Customers] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]);
Go
ALTER TABLE [Orders] Add [Customer_Id] INT;
GO
```

### Excepion with 'GO' Keywords

"There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 12,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = GO ]"

### Exception without 'GO' Keywords

"There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 12,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = ALTER ]"

Comment: please elaborate on how exactly it is not working

Comment: "Script" is not SQL. Is `Script` a variable name?

Comment: ` it is not working` what does it mean? Are you getting any error? What error?

Comment: Are `GO` batch statements allowed in Entity Framework? I didn't think they were.

Comment: I don't know for sure but I doubt SqlCE supports keyword "GO" which is not actually SQL, but a delimiter recognized by tools like SSMS.

Comment: I am getting an exception in 'Go' but I tired to delete 'Go' keywords and I got the exception in first Alter Table command

Comment: You would probably have to make 3 separate database calls.

Comment: But why is it working when I past same script in Sql Sever Compact ?

Comment: That tool probably understands GO as a batch delimiter.

Comment: OK Thanks. And Was there any library for sqlCE that understands 'Go' as a batch delimiter ?

Comment: I don't know, just execute 3 separate statements.

Comment: OK , Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Compact can only execute a single statement per batch, so you must remove the GO statement, and call ExecuteSqlCommand three times.